# Conversion of string array to vector of string type

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, initialization

I want to initialize a vector with following data of arr for that i have to initialize an array of string type and copy its value to vector string 
this is how i am doing it

it gives lots of errors

```
string arr[6][8]={
"AAAAAAAA",
"ABWBWBWA",
"ABWBWBWA",
"ABWBWBWA",
"ABWBWBWA",
"AAAAAAAA"};
vector<string> v(arr,arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(string));
```

I have done it for int array and vector of int type.
Like this,

```
int vv[]={0,0,0,8};
vector<int> v(vv,vv+sizeof(vv)/sizeof(int));
```

and it works perfectly for this type but for string type its not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array makes no sense. It should be:

```
std::string arr[] = {
  "AAAAAAAA",
  "ABWBWBWA",
  "ABWBWBWA",
  "ABWBWBWA",
  "ABWBWBWA",
  "AAAAAAAA" };
```

Then

```
std::vector<std::string> v(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(std::string));
```

should work as expected.

Alternatively you can fix the `6` and say `v(arr, arr + 6);`.

In modern C++, however, you would just say,

```
std::vector<std::string> v {
  "AAAAAAAA",
  "ABWBWBWA",
  "ABWBWBWA",
  "ABWBWBWA",
  "ABWBWBWA",
  "AAAAAAAA"
};
```

Comment: can we do that in case of int type also?

Comment: std::vector<std::string> v {
    "AAAAAAAA",
    "ABWBWBWA",
    "ABWBWBWA",
    "ABWBWBWA",
    "ABWBWBWA",
    "AAAAAAAA"
    };

Comment: it says error: scalar object ‘v’ requires one element in initializer

Comment: @fsl4faisal: You need a modern compiler. In GCC, say `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"

Comment: @fsl4faisal: You just seem to have a very old compiler then... don't worry, use one of the other versions.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Do you think that Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 is not a modern compiler because it does not support initializer lists ?

Answer (score 0):

The type of `arr` is actually not `string` but `char[6][8]` (it is odd this compiles because you are initializing the members of this array with `char[9]` objects: the string literals include a terminating '\0' character). To properly get the size of a statically size arrays I always recommend **not** to use this C hack of using `sizeof()`. Instead, use a function template like this (in fact, I just included the `size()` template because you used the size; using `begin()` and `end()` to get iterators is superior):

```
template <typename T, int Size> int size(T (&array)[Size]) { return Size; }
template <typename T, int Size> T* begin(T (&array)[Size]) { return array; }
template <typename T, int Size> T* end(T (&array)[Size])   { return array + Size; }
...
std::vector<std::string> v(begin(arr), end(arr));
```

In C++2011 `begin()` and `end()` functions are part of the standand C++ library. Of course, with C++2011 you could directly use initializer lists.